# Outputting images in folder and clearing float After Every 6 Returned In Loop in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm trying to count the images in my folder and want to clear the float after each 6 images returned from a folder. Here's the code I've got so far but it spits out the clear more than the amount I'd like for it. Could somebody maybe guide me to a solution? Thanks in advance. Below is my code.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$dirname = "images"; 
$images = scandir($dirname);
$filecount = count(glob("images/". "*.png"));
 //echo $filecount;

$ignore = Array(".", "..", "otherfiletoignore");
foreach($images as $curimg){
if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {

if ($i % 6 === 0){

echo "<div style='clear:both;></div>'";

}

echo "<div style='float:left;'><img src='images/",$curimg."'"," /></div>";

}
}

?>
```

Comment: It is spitting the clear div before and after each image. I'm trying to clear the div after each 6 images in a folder. I hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not ever changing the value of `$i`, therefore it will be zero every time through the loop. In this situation you want to use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop.

```
$images = glob("images/*.png");
$filecount = count($images);
$ignore = Array(".", "..", "otherfiletoignore");
for ($i = 0; $i < $filecount; $i++){
    if(!in_array($images[$i], $ignore)) {
        if ($i % 6 === 0){
                echo "<div style='clear:both;></div>'";
        }
        echo "<div style='float:left;'><img src='images/",$images[$i]."'"," /></div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will spit out the line `echo "<div style='clear:both;></div>'";` on every iteration. This is because you have not incremented `$i` anywhere. `$i % 6 === 0` will always be true because `$i` is always zero.

Change:

```
if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {

if ($i % 6 === 0){
```

...to:

```
if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
$i++;
if ($i % 6 === 0){
```

...or use a `for` loop instead of `foreach`.